# Prevent Assigned by Reference

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am attempting to clone a few objects in an array based on some properties.

Given an array of objects:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    data: { 
      user: 
        {
          user1: 0,
          user2: 1,
        }
      }
   },
   {
    id: 2,
    data: { 
      user: 
        {
          user1: 0,
        }
      }
   },
]
```

I want to transform the above into:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    data: {
      user: 'user1',
      user_status: 0
    }
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    data: {
      user: 'user2',
      user_status: 1,
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    data: {
      user: 'user1',
      user_status: 0,
    }
  },
]
```

Every `user` object within the array should have its `user` property transformed regardless of how many properties are in the `user` object. There's other properties in the `data` object that I want to copy but do not wish to modify.

The closest I got was:

```
result.rows.forEach((item, index) => {

  for ( const user in item.data.user ) {
    const notif = Object.assign({}, item);
    notif.data.user = user;
    notif.data.user_status = item.data.user[user];
    result.rows.push(notif);
  }

});
```

However, the above acts as if `notif` it is assigned by reference(?) and is mutating the original object. Using a `console.log` during the `for in` loop results in:

```
console.log(notif.id, notif.data.user, notif.data.user_status)
// Results in 1, user1, undefined
console.log(item.data.user, item.data.user[user])
// Results in user1, undefined instead of the expect { 'user1': 0 }
```

This results in an array like:

```
{
  id: 1,
  data: {
    user: 'user2', // Should be user1
    user_status: undefined, // Should be 0
  }
},
{
  id: 1,
  data: {
    user: 'user2', // Should be user2 -- hooray but in a bad way
    user_status: undefined, // Should be 1
  }
}
```

All of this is running on a Node.js (8.11.1) server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` in your `item` references the original `data` object, because `Object.assign` gives a shallow clone, not a deep clone.

This would probably be achieved most elegantly by `reduce`-ing into an array in one go, extracting all the primitives immediately, rather than trying to work with the (by-reference) objects:

```js
const input=[{id:1,data:{user:{user1:0,user2:1,}}},{id:2,data:{user:{user1:0,}}},]

const output = input.reduce((a, { id, data: { user: users }}) => {
  Object.entries(users).forEach(([user, user_status]) => {
    a.push({ id, data: { user, user_status }});
  });
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

A fix to your original code would involve cloning the `data` property as well:

```js
const input=[{id:1,data:{user:{user1:0,user2:1,}}},{id:2,data:{user:{user1:0,}}},]
const output = [];

input.forEach((item, index) => {
  for (const user in item.data.user) {
    const notif = Object.assign({}, item);
    notif.data = Object.assign({}, item.data);
    notif.data.user = user;
    notif.data.user_status = item.data.user[user];
    output.push(notif);
  }

});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: I appreciate the simplicity of both. Had I read down the `Object.assign` docks I would of stumbled upon the second part of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using two [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loops. You can't loop with a [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) inside an object, instead, we will loop over [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) of the object. Which is essentially an array of keys.

Then for each fragment, for example

```
{
  id: 1,
  data: {
    user: 'user1',
    user_status: 0
  }
}
```

we can push a brand new object to `res`.

Here is the code:

```js
let res = [];
data.forEach((e, i, arr) => Object.keys(e.data.user).forEach((k, j) => {
  res.push({
    id: e.id,
    data: {
      user: k,
      user_status: j
    }
  });
}));

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script>
  const data=[{id:1,data:{user:{user1:0,user2:1,}}},{id:2,data:{user:{user1:0,}}}];
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to transform each object in the array using `map` into a subarray of new objects, then flatten the result using `reduce`.

```js
const input = [
  {
    id: 1,
    data: { 
      user: 
        {
          user1: 0,
          user2: 1,
        }
      }
   },
   {
    id: 2,
    data: { 
      user: 
        {
          user1: 0,
        }
      }
   },
];

const output = input.map(obj => Object.keys(obj.data.user)
    .map(user => ({
      id: obj.id, 
      data: {
        user, user_status: obj.data.user[user]
      }
    })
  ))
  .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b));

console.log(output)
```